# If element has class that has been dynamically added then do

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element which has a class added through a function which I would like to do a check on..

If ELEMENT has class then show another element

I've got an if else statement which I thought would work but class="selected" seems to only work when the page isnt dynamically changing the class.

Im using jquery isotope as a filtering tool, which is adding the selected class if that helps.

```
if ($("#comingsoonfilter").hasClass('selected')){ //this gets dynamically added
    $("#datesorter").css({
        'display' : 'block'
    });
} else {
    $("#datesorter").css({
        'display' : 'none'
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="filter big">
    <p>Filter Schemes:</p>
    <ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All Schemes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".comingsoon" id="comingsoonfilter">Coming Soon</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
    <p>View by:</p>
    <ul id="sort-by" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="sortBy">
        <li><a href="#sortBy=original-order" data-option-value="original-order" class="selected" data>Date Added</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sortBy=name" data-option-value="name">Alphabetical</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sortBy=price" data-option-value="price">Price</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sortBy=date" data-option-value="date" id="datesorter">Date</a></li>
    </ul>
```

ANSWER :

Had to fire the function in the same part as the bit that was adding the .selected class the whole part of javascript for this part (including the isotope is below), if anyone gets stuck.

```
$(function() {
    var $container = $('.scheme-archive');
    $checkboxes = $('#cityfilters input');
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.scheme',
                    getSortData : {
            price : function( $elem ) {
                return parseFloat( $elem.find('.price').text().replace( /[\£\,]/g, ''), 1000 );
            },
            date : function( $elem ) {
                return $elem.find('.date').text();
            },
            name : function ( $elem ) {
                return $elem.find('.name').text();
            }
        }
    });

    $checkboxes.change(function() {
        var filters = [];
        // get checked checkboxes values
        $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
            filters.push( this.value );
        });
        filters = filters.join(', ');
        $container.isotope({ filter: filters });
    });

    var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
        $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

    $optionLinks.click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
            return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');
        // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
        // Show / hide the date sorter
    if ($('.selected').is('#comingsoonfilter')){
                $('#datesorter').show();
        } else {
            $('#datesorter').hide();
        }
        var options = {},
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[ key ] = value;
        if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
            // changes in layout modes need extra logic
            changeLayoutMode( $this, options );
        } else {
            // otherwise, apply new options
            $container.isotope( options );
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is this block of code? if it's in your `$(document).ready()` function, then It will only check once, when the page loads

Comment: where are you using this code?

Comment: Naming conflict? Try a custom class name, e.g. 'myClass'

Comment: Can i have your HTML portion?

Comment: The fact it is added dynamically has no effect on `hasClass` at all.  It is probably the issue suggested above that your code is not running.  Press F12 and enter `$("#comingsoonfilter").hasClass('selected')` into the console.

Comment: It returns true and false as expected

I'm using the jqueryIsotope plugin which is adding the selected class - do you think this is the suspect?

The HTML is 2 lists, first list has #comingsoonfilter and the second list has #datesorter in. These fire the filters for jquery isotope

Comment: @BillyMathews its not in any .ready or load function, that was my first guess :(

Comment: @jamie When do you want it to happen? Why don't you try using `$('#datesorter').toggle();` in the same place as where you add the 'selected' class?

Comment: @BillyMathews Great idea, that should probably solve it - many thanks

Comment: And I'm not really sure why I was marked down, it was a valid question including code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try using `$('#datesorter').toggle();` in the same place as where you add the 'selected' class?

Comment: Had to use an if else - show / hide as toggle was causing issues